# Looking at SQL Code for Validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries that appear to be the same. We are trying to get quarter today.  One using a hard coded date and one not.  One query is returning 2100 less records.  The first and last record are the same. All of Feb match in both and the last 5 days in January match too.

Query 1 with hard coded date.

```
SELECT c.Account_RecordType
       ,timewait
       ,a.convotime
       ,DATENAME(Month, timewait) AS 'Mnth'
       ,DATENAME(year, timewait) AS 'yr'
       ,DATENAME(quarter, timewait) AS 'qrt'
    FROM SalesForce.dbo.SalesForceContact AS b
    INNER JOIN Dossier_Replication.dbo.vwSF_DATA_Contact c
        ON b.ContactID = c.CONTACTID__C
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN satVRS.dbo.rptNECACallHistory AS a
        ON b.UserID = a.UserID_Caller
    WHERE ( b.Platform = 'HandsonVRS' )
        AND ( a.timeWait BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-24' )
        AND ( a.isReport = '1' )
        AND ( a.NECA_isReport = '1' )
        AND ( a.ConvoTime > '0' )
        AND ( c.Account_RecordType = 'Enterprise Account' )
    GROUP BY c.Account_RecordType
       ,timewait
       ,a.convotime
```

Second query is pulling quarter,year, and day from the date field in question.

```
 SELECT c.Account_RecordType
       ,timewait
       ,a.convotime
       ,DATENAME(Month, timewait) AS 'Mnth'
       ,DATENAME(year, timewait) AS 'yr'
       ,DATENAME(quarter, timewait) AS 'qrt'
    FROM SalesForce.dbo.SalesForceContact AS b
    INNER JOIN Dossier_Replication.dbo.vwSF_DATA_Contact c
        ON b.ContactID = c.CONTACTID__C
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN satVRS.dbo.rptNECACallHistory AS a
        ON b.UserID = a.UserID_Caller
    WHERE ( b.Platform = 'HandsonVRS' )
        AND ( a.timeWait BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-24' )
        AND ( a.isReport = '1' )
        AND ( a.NECA_isReport = '1' )
        AND ( a.ConvoTime > '0' )
        AND ( c.Account_RecordType = 'Enterprise Account' )
    GROUP BY c.Account_RecordType
       ,timewait
       ,a.convotime
```

Does any one see anything obviously wrong with these two.  Any suggestions,  I thank you in advance.  We are running sql 2012

Comment: These two queries are identical, are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: Was just scratching my head at the same thing :)

Comment: Does your *timeWait* column stores Date AND Time ?. Your query will not return records whose *timeWait* is for example "2014-02-24 10:30:00"

Comment: You can CONVERT(DATE, a.timeWait) and see if that fixes it.  It will trim the time component from your timeWait field.

Comment: As Elliot cited both queries are identical. Are running both against the same DB, same schema, same, Server/instance using the same user?

Comment: The obvious answer is that the difference between the 2 queries is the date range.  Query 2 range is 01/01/2014 - 02/24/2014. Query 2 range is 01/01/2014 - 03/31/2014.  So is it possible there are records in your table with a future date?  Try running Query 1 with a date range of 01/01/2014 - 03/31/2014.  That will show if this is the issue or not.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, here is the second one...

select
    c.Account_RecordType,timewait,a.convotime,(datename(year,timewait))as twy,(datename(quarter,timewait))as twq

FROM  SalesForce.dbo.SalesForceContact AS b INNER JOIN
      Dossier_Replication.dbo.vwSF_DATA_Contact c ON b.ContactID = c.CONTACTID__C RIGHT OUTER JOIN
      satVRS.dbo.rptNECACallHistory AS a ON b.UserID = a.UserID_Caller

WHERE (b.Platform = 'HandsonVRS') 
                                  AND (datename(year,timewait))=(datename(year,getdate()-1)) AND (datename(quarter,timewait))=(datename(quarter,getdate()-1))
                                  AND (a.isReport = '1') 
                                  AND (a.NECA_isReport = '1') 
                                  AND (a.ConvoTime > '0')
                                  AND (c.Account_RecordType = 'Enterprise Account')
Group by    c.Account_RecordType,timewait,a.convotime
Order by timewait